# Javascript Function to Add/Remove Border from Box on Click

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the following script to add borders to the boxes on my pages:

```
<script>
 function highlight(target) {
  target.style.border = "1px solid red";
 }
</script>
```

However, I want to:

1. Limit users to only being able to hightlight/select 3 boxes
2. Allow users to "un-border" or "unhighlight" these boxes by clicking on them for a second time.

I have tried adding the following piece of code into the function but it did not work.

> target.onclick = null;

How can this be done?

Comment: please provide your html code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Limit users to only being able to hightlight/select 3 boxes

For the first purpose you can have a global variable which will hold the number of checked items. Like below:

```
 var selected_items = 0;
 function highlight(target) {
  if(selected_items < 3){
    target.style.border = "1px solid red";
    // add 1 each time an item is selected
    selected_items += 1;
  }
  target.style.border = "1px solid red";
 }
```

> 2. Allow users to "un-border" or "unhighlight" these boxes by clicking on them for a second time.
>      And For the second one you can check if the current value of border is empty.
>      So your code would be like this:

```
 var selected_items = 0;
 function highlight(target) {
  // check if the current border is empty (or if default one is sth else you can replace it with the "" and put your desired border value)
  if(target.style.border == ""){
    if(selected_items < 4){
       target.style.border = "1px solid red";
       selected_items += 1;
    }
  }
  else{
    target.style.border = "";
    selected_items -= 1;
  }

 }
```

At the end I recommend you to add a class or remove a class to make the items have border instead of changing the items directly . This would be easier for your other purchases in the future too.

Comment: Thanks! Just to note, selected_items has to be less than 3, not 4. Much appreciated!

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the 3. I did change it to fit to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by keeping a variable containing the number of selected elements and using a css class for your "selected" state and adding it and removing it from the element as appropriate:

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
var numSelected = 0;
var maxSelected = 3;
for(var i = 0;i<boxes.length;i++){
    boxes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){        
        if(this.classList.contains("selected")){
            this.classList.remove("selected");
            numSelected--;
        }
        else if(numSelected<maxSelected){
            this.classList.add("selected");
            numSelected++;
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.box {
  height:20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 2px
}

.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```